# How to choose an ios image and display it in Nativescript using imagepicker

Tags: nativescript, phasset

I am using imagepicker https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker in Nativescript to select and display an image in my app. This was very simple using Android, but I can't figure out how to do it using IOS. I have found a few examples online, but I am assuming they are out of date because they didn't work.

```
 this.imagePicker.onSelectSingleTap().then(
            (imageAsset: any) => {

                if (!isAndroid) {
                   // What do I do here?
                }
                if (isAndroid) {
                    this.imgURL = imageAsset.android;

                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: iOS doesn't give you the image path instead it gives you the PHAsset object. You should write the image asset to a file in your documents or temp directory. Or if you just want to display it on screen, simply create ImageSource from ImageAsset and assign it to Image component.

Comment: Do you have any code examples for how to do this?

Comment: Refer the [ImageSource docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/image-source#save-image-from-image-asset-to-png-file)